# Primefaces do not submit hidden input

Tags: jsf, input, primefaces, hidden, hiddenfield

I'm using Primefaces 5.0.4 and JSF 2.2. I have a dataTable with some hidden inputs in the rows for setting some js values. My Problem is that i want to submit the Table, but not the hidden inputs, because they refer to a non writeable property. Is this possible?

best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using an HTML hidden field will solve your problem, it will not prevent them from being submitted but they will not update your JSF backing beans.

```
<input type="hidden" value="#{yourBean.value}" />
```

This input can be used as usual via JavaScript, you can also assign directly the bean value to a js variable on your page.

As per your comment, i've updated my suggestion. Your can also use a JS table that will hold all your table values just add on each row some JS as shown below:

```
<script>table['#{yourBean.someId}'] = '#{yourBean.value}';</script>
```

dont forget to declare the js table variable outside your datatable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried <input type="hidden"...> instead of <h:inputHidden...> which does break my jquery dnd for any reason. It just stops after processing the table without any console error

Comment: Sorry this was my fault, I updated the table after processing, so my dnd broke. Removing the update it works now, even if it may is not the way to go as BalusC already mentioned. Does anyone have an idea how this is done the fine way?

Comment: thanks, I totally appreciate your answer. Creating a JS array in with the size of the table as an alternative. But since it does work with your first option I'll keep this one. I think it's more confortable to read. Thanks anyways ;)

Comment: You're welcome, could you please accept the answer if it's satisfactory for you.

Comment: Hi, I know this topic is answered but I got an advanced question regarding to this: I now created a javascript Map with key = rowId and value = #{bean.getAmount(rowKey)}. On push the row gets updated, but the javascript Map does not get the new values. I added the following script tag in one column: <script> object[rowKey] = #{bean.getAmount(rowKey)}. How can I update the javascript value if the row gets updated?

Comment: Make sure to update the datatable every time these values a are updated on the server side.